# mingw-64 conflicting declarations when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, windows, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile for Windows using mingw-64 within Eclipse in Ubuntu Trusty (I am not using the automatic makefile feature). All is well except some conflicting declarations from the mingw-64 headers for example:

```
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winbase.h:31:0,
             from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:70,
             from ../[...].cpp:532:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/profileapi.h: At global scope:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/profileapi.h:16:87: error: declaration of C function ‘WINBOOL QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER*)’ conflicts with
WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceCounter (LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount);
```

Like I said I'm new to cross compiling, so is this indicative of a common cross-compiling mistake? If not, will I need to build mingw from source to remove a small number (<10) of conflict declarations?

Comment: Where does the compiler say the conflicting definition came from?

Comment: Snipped edited to show complete error message

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other declaration. The compiler usually tells you where that is as well. It should be mentioned on the following line(s).